# Neo4j : EntityNotFoundException: Node with id + Inconsistencies

Tags: nosql, neo4j, debian

I successfully migrated from **Neo4J 2.0.0.M6 Community Edition** to **2.0.0.RC1 Enterprise Edition**.

But...
When i'm doing this query :

`neo4j-sh (?)$ START n=node(4) RETURN n;`

The answer is

`EntityNotFoundException: Node with id 4`

When I'm doing a neo4j-backup, It generate **Inconsistencies errors**

```
2014-01-25 21:19:58.808+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: ERROR: This label scan document refers to a node record that is not in use.
NodeLabelRange[docId=2; {Node[3]: Labels[0], Node[4]: Labels[1], Node[5]: Labels[1], Node[6]: Labels[1], Node[7]: Labels[1], Node[8]: Labels[0], Node[9]: Labels[1], Node[10]: Labels[1], Node[11]: Labels[1], Node[12]: Labels[0], Node[13]: Labels[1], Node[14]: Labels[1], Node[15]: Labels[0], Node[17]: Labels[1], Node[16]: Labels[1], Node[19]: Labels[1], Node[18]: Labels[0], Node[21]: Labels[1], Node[20]: Labels[1], Node[23]: Labels[1], Node[22]: Labels[1], Node[25]: Labels[1], Node[24]: Labels[1], Node[27]: Labels[1], Node[26]: Labels[0], Node[29]: Labels[1], Node[28]: Labels[1], Node[31]: Labels[0], Node[30]: Labels[1]}
Inconsistent with: Node[30,used=false,rel=0,prop=0,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light]. 100% 

2014-01-25 21:19:58.809+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Inconsistencies found:
    ConsistencySummaryStatistics{
    Number of errors: 28
    Number of warnings: 0
    Number of inconsistent LABEL_SCAN_DOCUMENT records: 1
```

I have inconsistencies on nodes 3 -> 30.
I'n not using those nodes anymore so I tried to delete them without success...

So... How can I remove them or fix the problem ?

Thank you !
Bons baisers de France :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual upgrade neded to move from 2.0.0-M06 to 2.0.0-RC1 (or 2.0.0) is documented here:

http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/11/neo4j-200-rc1-final-preparations.html

### Caution: manual upgrade between milestones

Data stores created with any previous milestone version can not be used with 2.0.0-RC1 unless a manual upgrade is performed. This is due to incompatible changes made to the store files. Please proceed with caution, backing up your data before attempting to manually upgrade.

### Manual upgrade (only from 2.0.0-M06, and after you've backed up):

- Cleanly shut down on the old version on Neo4j 2.0.0-M06

  `bin/neo4j stop`
- Navigate to the database directory

  `cd data/graph.db`
- Delete the label scan store (this is the critical part that has a new format). It will be recreated on startup.

  `rm -rf schema/label`
- Start with the new version of Neo4j 2.0.0-RC1

  `bin/neo4j start`

Comment: Everything works perfect now thanks to this step by step upgrade :)  
I didn't search the right term for migrating and didn't found this blog post.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Repairing a inconsistent datastore is often possible but requires a) deep insight into the internal data structures and b) a serious amount of manual work.

Since you've moved from 2.0.0-M06 -> 2.0.0-RC1 my guess is that the source of the inconsistency has already been resolved in 2.0.0. Please be aware that milestone builds do not have production quality.

The most easy way would be to rebuild your database from scratch is possible. If that is not possible and the database is rather small you might be able to use the `DUMP` command in neo4j-shell to export your full dataset into cypher create statements and apply these on a fresh 2.0.0 database.